# Applying De Morgan's Law?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Assume that the sets $A$, $B$, $C$ are different sets.

a) Applying De Morgan's Law, determine the other side of $(A∪C)'=$

b) Applying De Morgan's Law, determine the other side of $(B'∩C')'=$

I want to know if what I did is right.

a) $(A∪C)'=A'∩C'$

b) $(B'∩C')'=B∪C$

If I'm wrong let me know please. I just know that for two sets $A$ and $B$, the De Morgan's Law states that $(A∪B)'= A'∩B'$ and $(A∩B)'= A'∪B'$. I don't know if the same applies when there are three sets.

Comment: Your work is fine.

Comment: The same applies with three sets as well.  $(A\cup B\cup C)' = A'\cap B'\cap C'$.  To see this, remember that $(A\cup B\cup C) = ((A\cup B)\cup C)$ and that $A\cup B$ is a set, so we have rewritten the union of three sets as the union of two sets (*one of which happens to itself be a union of two sets too*). so we have $((A\cup B)\cup C)' = (A\cup B)'\cap C'$ and we use DeMorgan again to get $(A'\cap B')\cap C'$.  You can apply induction to generalize to any number of sets.

Comment: @JMoravitz this should be an answer in my opinion.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the set symbols used in de Morgan's laws may be substituted with any set symbols.  That is the purpose. The laws are *substitution schemas*.

$$\begin{split}(\mathrm A\cup\mathrm B)' &= \mathrm A'\cap \mathrm B' &\qquad&\text{for any sets }\mathrm A,\mathrm B
\\[4ex](A\cup C)'&=A'\cap C'&&\text{for particular sets }A,C\\[2ex]((X\cup Y)\cup Z)'&=(X\cup Y)'\cap Z'&&\text{for particular sets }(X\cup Y), Z\\&=(X'\cap Y')\cap Z'&&\text{also this too}\end{split}$$